# Knockout validation change error message

Tags: typescript, knockout.js, knockout-validation

I am trying to change the error message for a particular field. Here's whats I have so far.

```
var errorMsg = fieldHidden ? "Please do something" : "Hidden field error Msg";

ko.validation.rules["validation"] = {
    validator: (value) => {
        if (ko.validation.utils.isEmptyVal(value)) {
            return true;
        }
    },
    message: errorMsg
};
```

I already have the code to display the message separately at the top of the page. if the field is hidden

```
<div><p style="color: red" data-bind="validationMessage: personal().postal"></p></div>
```

For some reason the message stays the same. Please help thanks.

Other things i tried:(After submit button is hit)

```
var errors = ko.validation.group(self.personalViewModel, { deep: true });
    if (fieldHidden()) {
        errors()[0] = "New error message";
    }
    errors.showAllMessages();
```

Even though this changes the message when i check the chrome debugger, the old message still gets displayed.

Comment: try making `errorMsg` as ko observable or check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43682332/knockout-validation-dynamic-validation-message#answer-43683672)

Comment: @Jag making message a function worked for some reason.  message: () => { }